# NORX duplex padding

Tags: authenticated-encryption, padding, sponge

[MonkeyDuplex](http://keccak.noekeon.org/KeccakDIAC2012.pdf) constructions defined by Keccak authors has padding in every duplex block.

Why only last duplex block is padded in [NORX](https://norx.io/data/norx.pdf)?

Is it because NORX has domain separation, or simply because Keccak authors defined duplex on top of sponge and it isn't actually needed, or ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MonkeyDuplex in NORX does not have padding per duplex because it does not need thanks to domain separation. As the plaintext is mixed into the ciphertext, it does so at the sponge rate, the same way as Keccak does during normal sponge operations. This makes it more efficient at the given security level.

The standard MonkeyDuplex construction does not have domain separation, but when used by NORX is closer to SpongeWrap (MonkeySpongeWrap?), which uses a fixed rate per spec and a different domain constant for the last plaintext block, so there is no chance of an input collision for a padded block vs an unpadded block, which is why the purpose of padding for the standard MonkeyDuplex without domain separation.

If you look at [the spec of NORX](https://norx.io/data/norx.pdf) (PDF) you will see that this is actually not true, and that the first trailer block can collide with the last plaintext block. However this is not a security problem because there is no data outputted at this stage, and there is still a final domain separation before tag generation.